# How can I log result from httprequest in protractor?

Tags: angularjs, protractor

My angular controller looks like this:

```
myApp.controller('Ctrl1', ['$scope','$http', function ($scope,$http) {
    console.log('hello');
    $scope.testing = 'hello man';
$http.get("https://api.github.com/repos/vmg/redcarpet/issues").success(function (data) {
        // success
        console.log('success');


    }).error(function (error) {
        // error
        console.log(JSON.stringify("Failed to get t&c: " + error));
    });

}]);
```

My e2e test looks like this:

```
afterEach(function () {
                browser.manage().logs().get('browser').then(
                    function (browserLog) {
                        console.log('\n log: ' + require('util').inspect(browserLog));
                    });
            });


    it('should show success in console', function () {
                browser.get('http://localhost:63342/basic_protractor_osx/index.html');

            });
```

When I run protractor the log array is empty, while when I open de index.html with the controller it displays 'success' in the console. How can I test the controller with protractor so I can test for success?

Answer (score 0):

You must define you want to get logs from the browser in the capatibilities in conf.js

```
capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    'chromeOptions': {
        args: ['--test-type']
    },
    'loggingPrefs': {
        browser: 'ALL'
    }
},
```

then get the logs from the browser as you did.

Comment: still does not return the console.log from the http call?

Comment: @bierhier what does your `require('util').inspect(browserLog)` do? try just to print it `console.log(browserLog);`